# Bitcoin Wallet Recovery

Tags: wallet, private-key

Hypothetically, if you formatted over a hard drive and erased your wallet but had your private key and address written down- how would you once again regain access to your wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import your private key into a new wallet, most wallets support private key imports. The private key is all you need to know.